# Twisted product

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, algebraic-topology, products

I'm reading about $SO(n)$ in Hatcher's algebraic topology, where is said that for $n\notin\{1,2,3,4,8\}$ $SO(n)$ is a **‘twisted product’** of $SO(n − 1)$
and $S^{n−1}$.

What is a twisted product? Where can I read more about this?

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: He means there is a nontrivial fibration $SO(n-1)\to SO(n)\to S^{n-1}$