# Reference for contracted product $X \times^G Y$

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-groups, principal-bundles

I've seen a superscript on $\times$ a few times now in the setting of $G$-spaces, and I can't find any documentation of its definition or basic properties, as I have no idea what to search.

Given an algebraic group $G$, a right $G$-torsor $X \to S$, and a left $G$-space $Y$, how is the space $X \times^G Y$ defined, and what is it called?

An example of its use (from Richarz, "A new approach to the geometric Satake equivalence"; note that $\mathrm{Gr}_G$ is a right $fpqc$-quotient $\mathrm{Gr}_G := LG/L^+G$):

> Consider the following diagram of ind-schemes
> $$
> \mathrm{Gr}_G \times \mathrm{Gr}_G \overset{p}{\leftarrow} LG \times \mathrm{Gr}_G \overset{q}{\to} LG \times^{L^+G} \mathrm{Gr}_G \overset{m}{\to} \mathrm{Gr}_G.
> $$
> Here $p$ (resp. $q$) is a right $L^+G$-torsor with respect to the $L^+G$-action on the left factor (resp. the diagonal action). The $LG$-action on $\mathrm{Gr}_G$ factors through $q$, giving rise to the morphism $m$.

If I want to take this as a definition (quotient a Cartesian product of two $G$-sets by the diagonal action), I am still not sure what kind of quotient I should be using, and I have some further questions I'd rather not probe alone if I don't have to.

When is $X \times^G Y$ a $G$-torsor, an $fpqc$ sheaf, an algebraic space, an ind-scheme, etc.? Does the side of the $G$-action on $X$ or $Y$ matter for the definition? Is the notation symmetric in $X$ and $Y$? Is it necessary that $X$ be a torsor? Are there other necessary conditions to define the space?

**Edit:** after some random browsing here and on Overflow, I have found two possible names for the object and a possible definition. It is referred to as either a twisted product or a contracted product. I want to point out that none of the questions linked below have answers (outside of some fairly brief comments) or any references, so I would greatly appreciate a basic reference. I still can't seem to find any.

[What is the algebraic interpretation of a contracted product? (MSE)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3766125/what-is-the-algebraic-interpretation-of-a-contracted-product)

[Twisted product (MSE)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2090578/twisted-product)

[Contracted product of torsors (MO)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/271260/contracted-product-of-torsors)

Question 3 includes a definition, and asks some of the same questions I'm interested in, but imposes some more conditions on the spaces involved than I thought would be necessary.

Comment: I originally thought it might be just a fibre product, but that is usually written $\times_G$ rather than $\times^G$. All of these things are basically the same, take a product and 'quotient out' by the action. The exact description that you have at the end I'm not entirely sure about though, it depends on some conventions I think. It will be commutative for a suitable definition of such a thing, as long as you take enough opposites. (For this to be the case, both will have to be torsors, of course.)

Comment: There is another definition here: https://ayoucis.files.wordpress.com/2019/11/torsors.pdf on p15, which seems to only require one to be a torsor (as far as my reading diagonally suggests) which yields the same answer as the third question, but at first glance relaxes some conditions.

Comment: (Clarification: I am far from an expert on this stuff!)

Comment: No worries, and thanks for sharing a relevant paper. I really doubt it's a fiber product, since I'd expect the natural maps to go $\times_G \to \times \to \times^G$, and not the other way around.

Comment: Exactly. That matches up with the subscript to superscript. I suspect it's the categorical dual, so whichever one is the pullback, the other is the pushout, but I never remember which is which.

Comment: It seems a good reference for this might be Emsalem, M. (2017). Twisting by a Torsor. In: Aryasomayajula, A., Biswas, I., Morye, A.S., Parameswaran, A.J. (eds) Analytic and Algebraic Geometry. Springer, Singapore.